# GSM+GPS modules

Tags: gsm, gps

Say, I need to track a vehicle using Arduino and a (GPS+GSM) module.  Though GPS can be used to get Location of the Vehicle(and then sent using GSM), why would we even do it using GPS if we already have a GSM module. Can't GSM do both these tasks(getting location and sending it) . What's the use of using an extra module there?

I am new to network stuff, help me!

Comment: Only a few GSM modules also include a GPS module. Without that all you could possibly get is the cell ID, which is pretty pointless.

Comment: Did you mean that GSM technology alone cannot find out its location?

Comment: That is correct. GSM can only get you the cell ID (rough location) and signal strength (could be used to approximate distance from tower?) It certainly can't get you a lat/long. Only a "You're in the south west of Fort Worth"...

Comment: Well thanks! That answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

The GSM module can estimate it's location based on cell tower triangulation but if you want a more accurate location then you need to use a GPS.